# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+x^n}dx$

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Find $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{n}{1+x^n}dx$$

Lebesgue dominated convergence does not work. My next thought was to use Fatou's lemma and reverse Fatou's lemma to bound the integral, but I haven't the faintest idea how to calculate the liminf or limsup of the integrand. Wolfram Alpha tells me that the value of the integral decreases (starting with n=2) from about 1.2 to about 0.7, but I can't even show that the sequence is decreasing right now.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $u=x^n$ to get:
$$I_n:=\int^\infty_1\frac{n}{1+x^n}\,dx=\int^\infty_1 \frac{1}{u^\frac{n-1}{n}(1+u)}\,du$$
For $n\geq 2$, the inequality $u^\frac{n-1}{n}\geq u^\frac{1}{2}$ holds pointwise for $u\in [1,\infty)$ so:
\begin{align}
\left| \frac{1}{u^\frac{n-1}{n}(1+u)}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[]{u}(1+u)}
\end{align} Hence by dominated convergence theorem we get:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n = \int^\infty_1 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{u^\frac{n-1}{n}(1+u)}\,du=\int^\infty_1 \frac{1}{u(1+u)}\,du = \log(2)
\end{align}
And indeed $\log(2)\approx 0.7$.